# Finding Attachment \ Part ID using Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, yahoo

I'm trying to find an attachment id.
When I receive an email with 3 attachments for example, I cannot find their ID or any unique key that will identify them.

I'm using a Yahoo mail account. Also, I cannot find any header or something that is even close to id \ unique key for the attachment.

If I use "inspect element" on the email it self, I can find this line for example:

```
<li tabindex="0" role="presentation" class="tictac-att-other   " data-id="9" data-type="TXT" title="get all folders.TXT (2.4KB)" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1427784055060_2939"></li>
```

So I guess that ID exist, how can I get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While the MIME standard defines a [Content-ID header for MIME parts](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimePart.html#getContentID()), including "attachments", it's not required.  I don't know where the line you found comes from, but it looks like it's part of the content of the attachment, or possibly part of how your mailer or browser is displaying the attachment, and not part of the MIME metadata for the message.

How do you want to use this "id" if it exists?

Comment: I have found that for every attachments that are not .TXT files, there is a content ID for that part \ attachment.

However, for some .txt files there is Content-ID and for some there isn't.
I can't figure out why it happens...
Even if I look at the headers, there is no mention for Content-ID for those .txt files... ( which is weird cause for some of them there is Content-ID available...)

Comment: Like I said, it's not required, so some mailers are going to put it there and some are not.  You can't even assume that all non-text attachments are going to have a Content-ID even though every one you looked at happened to.

Comment: so how can you identify specific attachments?
Lets say you have an 5 messages with 10 attachments each, if you want to find a specific attachment everytime, you need to go over all of them? that's seems unlikely...

Comment: You can identify the message, using either the Message-ID (also not guaranteed) or the message's UID, depending on your needs.  The second attachment for that message will always be the second attachment for that message.  The same way you find it the first time you look for it in that message will be the same way you find it every other time you look for it in that message.  If you need to come up with a single number or string to identify an attachment, it's up to you to decide how to do that, based on your needs.  There is not one right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bill!
I have found out that emails with attachments that are sent from email accounts that are not yahoo, do not get content ID, while mails from Yahoo does...
This is kinda weird.
But I think the only option is to use the Message-ID and number the attachments inside the message.

How come the Message-ID is not guaranteed?

Comment: There's not a simple answer to that question.